Jitsi Meet Flutter sdk black screen(No video, no audio) on Android 10, 11
I'm currently integrating the Jitsi Meet SDK into my Flutter Android application. The integration works flawlessly on newer Android versions, but I'm encountering issues when running the app on older devices, specifically those running Android 10 and Android 11.
class JitsiSdk {
  static DateTime? _startDate;

  static void hangUp() async {
    JitsiMeet().hangUp();
  }

  static Future<void> join(String callId,
      {Function(String? str)? onParticipantLeft,
      Function(int duration)? onClosed,
      bool? isBackground = false,
      bool showInviteButton = false}) async {
    if (isBackground == true) {
      await EncryptedSharedPreferences.initialize(Env.prefKey);
    }
    final displayName = "Test";
    final avatarId = "avatar";
    JitsiMeet().join(
      JitsiMeetConferenceOptions(
        token: SharedPreferences.getInstance().getString(Keys.token),
        featureFlags: {
          "invite.enabled": showInviteButton,
          "add-people.enabled": showInviteButton,
          "security-options.enabled": false,
          "prejoinpage.enabled": true,
          "calendar.enabled": false,
          'prejoinpage.hideDisplayName': true,
          "toolbox.enabled": true,
          "settings.enabled": false,
          "speakerstats.enabled": false,
          "lobby-mode.enabled": false,
          "server-url-change.enabled": false,
          "sourceNameSignaling": true,
          "notifications.enabled": false,
          "sendMultipleVideoStreams": true,
          "receiveMultipleVideoStreams": true,
          "pip.enabled": false,
          "help.enabled": false,
          "recording.enabled": false,
        },
        configOverrides: {
          // "startWithAudioMuted": false,
          "help.enabled": false,
          // "startWithVideoMuted": false,
          "settings.enabled": false,
          "pip.enabled": false,
          "subject": Strings.call,
          // "notifications.enabled": false,
          "sendMultipleVideoStreams": true,
          "receiveMultipleVideoStreams": true,
        },
        room: callId,
        serverURL: networkRelease.replaceAll(":9001", ":8443"),
        userInfo: JitsiMeetUserInfo(
            email: "", displayName: displayName, avatar: NetworkUtils.fileUrl(avatarId)),
      ),
      JitsiMeetEventListener(
        conferenceTerminated: (str, obj) {
          final duration = DateTime.now().difference(_startDate!);
          onClosed?.call(duration.inSeconds);
        },
        conferenceJoined: (str) {
          _startDate = DateTime.now();
        },
        participantLeft: (str) {
          onParticipantLeft?.call(str);
        },
        readyToClose: () {
          if (_startDate != null) {
            final duration = DateTime.now().difference(_startDate!);
            onClosed?.call(duration.inSeconds);
          } else {
            onClosed?.call(0);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

How can fix this? All permissions allowed
Manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true"
    tools:targetApi="eclair" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"
    tools:targetApi="eclair" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true"
    tools:targetApi="eclair" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true"
    tools:targetApi="eclair" />

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk

Are there any error messages you can post? You should also update the title to say "Jitsi". If you are using the SDK here it states it requires Android 6 (API 23) or newer. Unfortunately I can't help answer but I can check that.
